# Which IDE is compatible/suitable for developing Flutter/Dart Apps on Apple Silicon M1 so that I can test on ios Simulator and android Emulator?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, android-emulator, ios-simulator, apple-silicon

I want to develop and test app on simulator/emulator using Flutter on **Apple Silicon M1**. Please suggest which IDE should I use and things I should keep in mind or limitation before starting development.

Comment: Github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Developing-with-Flutter-on-Apple-Silicon

Comment: Visual Studio Code for M1 Macs: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/#

Comment: ok. let me try with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive tried with both android studio and VS code and it seems both are fine. But android emulator is not supporting as of now which is issue with M1, nothing related to flutter/Dart or any IDE .
We have to download and install from below link https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases/tag/0.1

Answer (score 0):

Use vs-code insider edition since it's optimised for Apple Silicon M1.